# Can we have any useful first order programs with infinite lists?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, scheme, infinite

I am trying to come up with an example for infinite lists in a lazy first order language that i have implemented. I wanted to know if there are any useful programs which use infinite lists, but do not use any higher order functions.

Comment: If you have a useful program with higher order functions, just rewrite it to use first order functions.

Answer (score 2):

I used an infinite list to represent players in a game recently:

```hs
let playerList = [PlayerA, PlayerB]
let players = cycle playerList

let currentPlayer = head players
let advance = tail players -- "save" this to your players "variable"

-- or, maybe clearer, inside of MonadState [Player]
let advance' = modify tail
```

I think you could come up with *a lot* more.